# Difference between the injective object in the category of cochain complexes of modules and injective cochain complexes

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, functors, injective-module

There is a question completely ignored in the literature which is very strange considering how natural this question arises. I regard this as an omission and I hope to be able to clarify this matter here.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of cochain complexes in the category of $R$-modules. Let $I^{\bullet}$ be an invective resolution of an $R$-module $M$. Is then the complex $I^{\bullet}$ an injective object in $\mathcal{C}$ in the sense that the functor $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(-, I^{\bullet})$ is an exact functor? If not then what are the injective object in the category of cochain complexes? Thanks.

Comment: It is not completely ignored in the literature, it's just usually stated in terms of projective objects. There are multiple questions about projective objects in the category of complexes, and then you can get the injectives by considering the opposite category.

Comment: For instance: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115449/projective-objects-in-the-category-of-chain-complexes

Comment: But let me clarify the most obvious thing first. As far as I understand, an injective resolution $I^{\bullet}$ of an $R$-module is NOT necessarily an injective object in the category of cochain complexes of $R$-modules, is it? Meaning $\mathrm{Hom}_{\textrm{Comp}(R-\textrm{Mod})}(-, I^{\bullet})$ is not an exact functor?